# How do I prevent NULLs from causing the wrong datatype in a Dataframe?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, pandas-datareader, pypyodbc

I am using Pandas "read_sql" to pull a data set from SQL Server into a dataframe, using Pypyodbc.  However, it looks like sometimes (NOT ALWAYS), when there are NULLs in a field, the datatype isn't int64, but float64.

I have two fields that are both declare as INT in SQL Server.  One sometimes has NULLs, the other one appears to always have NULLs.

Here's the schema in SQL Server:

```
[PLAN_ID] [int] NULL,
[DESTINATION_ID] [int] NULL,
[STORE_ID] [int] NULL,
```

If I use **dict** to look at those fields, I see:
(there's others, but I'm not sure how to read DICT, so I'm including the previous line)

```
Name: plan_id, Length: 13193, dtype: int64, 'destination_id': 0        None
1        None
2        None
3        None
4        None
         ...
13188    None
13189    None
13190    None
13191    None
13192    None
Name: dest_id, Length: 13193, dtype: object, 'store_id': 0        175635.0
1        180942.0
2             NaN
3             NaN
4             NaN
           ...
13188     59794.0
13189    180015.0
13190     94819.0
13191    184716.0
13192    182301.0
Name: store_id, Length: 13193, dtype: float64, 'version': 0
```

Here's the code I'm using

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc
from datetime import timedelta, date

start_date = date(2019, 5, 1)
end_date = date(2019, 5, 2)
daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)

con_string = ('Driver={SQL Server};'
'Server=mysqlservername;'
'Database=mydbname;'
'App=PythonPull;'  #It's not "application name"!
'Trusted_Connection=yes')
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(con_string)


for single_date in daterange:
    datestr = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print(datestr)
    tablelist = ["mytablenamehere"]
    for item in tablelist:
        query = f"""
        declare @start_date datetime = '{datestr}'
        declare @end_date   datetime  = dateadd(day,1,'{datestr}')
        SELECT id, customerid FROM mydbname.dbo.{item} with (nolock)
        where submitted >= @start_date and submitted < @end_date
        order by submitted
        """
        result_list = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
        #at this point, running result_port_map.__dict__ shows that the ID is an int64, but the customerid is a float64
```

Comment: `int64` cannot hold `NaN` as `NaN` is a float. A bad option is to convert the column to `object`, which can hold both. Otherwise you can try the `Int64` dtype (notice the capital I).

Comment: @ALollz thanks! Now to Google how to do the convert. :)

Comment: @ALollz just curious, why is it a bad option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a neat trick using pandas 0.24.0+:

Use `astype` with `pd.Int64Dtype` [nullable Integer datatypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#integer-dtypes-and-missing-data)

MVCE:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, np.nan]
s = pd.Series(l)
```

Ouput s:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64

s.dtype

dtype('float64')
```

Now, let's use `astype` with `pd.Int64Dtype`:

```
s = s.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Output s:

```
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
dtype: Int64

s.dtype

Int64Dtype
```

Comment: Gig'em, and thanks!  Is there any way to automatically convert any float64s to INT/BIGINT, or do I have to tell it on every field?  I've got 50 tables, each with dozens of fields, and read_sql/read_sql_query doesn't appear to have any good solutions/

Comment: Here's a pretty cool way of doing that.  `df.assign(**df.select_dtypes(include='float').astype(pd.Int64Dtype()))`   Gig'em!

Comment: one last one for you - Is there any way to say "change any of these fields if they exist"?  I just realized that I have other floats that are valid decimals, so now I'm looking at changing just the fields that need id.  Lookup IDs, basically.  I was trying `convert_dict = {"A": Int64Dtype}` and then `df=df.astype(convert_dict)` , but it says Int64Dtype is not defined.  I did get `df['A'] = df['A'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())` to work, but if the field doesn't exist, then it barfs, (just like the convert_dict).  Thanks again!

Comment: This was very helpful. Just want to point out for others, you can also use a Int32Dtype (or 8, 16) if you don't need 64 bits and since you're already converting.